# What are the characteristic structures of bacillus M. tuberculosis and what they cause?

Tags: microbiology, homework, tuberculosis

I answered to this question:

> In most forms of the disease, the bacillus M. tuberculosis spreads slowly and widely
>   in the lungs, causing the formation of hard nodules (tubercles) in the
>   respiratory tissues and form cavities in the lungs.

and got zero points.

**What is the correct answer to the question?**

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia article on this ?

Comment: It is not sufficient and very bad. Must be exact in the answer and answer exactly to the question. My answer was apparently too general.